# My recordset is having a record count of -1?

Tags: sql, asp-classic

In my classic asp app, I am calling a stored procedure and it is supposed to get me a record set through a select statement. If I try the stored procedure select statement in the sql management studio, I get like 100 rows, but when I try calling it in class asp code, I get a record set that has a record count of -1.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

```
Dim Conn
SET rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
SET Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Conn.CommandText = "sp_selectNewHireSQL"
Conn.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Conn.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
Set rsGetHireID = Conn.Execute


NumOfHireID = rsGetHireID.RecordCount
Response.Write (NumOfHireID)
```

**OLD working code:**

```
newHireSQL = "select * from NewHire where Archived = 0 order by HireID desc"
Set rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsGetHireID.Open newHireSQL,ConnectionString,adOpenStatic
```

NEW EDIT:
It seems the fix was to remove the BEGIN and END from the stored procedure, which was causing a loop.

Comment: Maybe it's not the record count but the return value? Please show some code!

Comment: Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the stored procedure?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove the BEGIN and END that the stored procedure template puts by default. Having those causes a loop.

Comment: if you're going to blame the stored proc, at least post the proc code. i've never heard of a `BEGIN` loop ...

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that your problem is the type of cursor you are opening on your recordset. Not all of them support the recordcount property.

From MSDN

> Use the RecordCount property to find out how many records are in a
>   Recordset object. **The property returns -1 when ADO cannot determine
>   the number of records or if the provider or cursor type does not
>   support RecordCount**. Reading the RecordCount property on a closed
>   Recordset causes an error.

To specify the cursor type you will need to use the open method on the recordset object.

```
'use CursorType=3 (Static)
rsGetHireID .Open CommandObjectOrSQLQuery, Conn , CursorType
```

Comment: Is it because of the way I wrote my stored procedure? So I need to keep it like this `SET NOCOUNT OFF;`?

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with that. It is exactly what I said in my answer. Just use the new syntax to open the recordset and you will be fine.

Comment: I updated my original post with the old working code, can you edit your code so it works with the variables I have? I want to use the stored procedure method. Also what do I put for `CommandObjectOrSQLQuery`?

Comment: You need to create a command object for the stored proc call. (http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_command.asp) and pass that in.

Comment: Would I put in adOpenStatic for cursortype?

Answer (score 0):

the easy way you may use..

1.rsGetHireID.open newHireSQL,Conn,1,3

Thanx

Comment: I want to use the stored procedure.